# Delete music on iPhone

Tags: iphone, music

I have iOS 7 and I know how to work all of it but when there was iOS 6 all music you've bought on iTunes, could be deleted from the device. Now I you remove songs that you've bought on the device stay there with the stupid iCloud download symbol. I want it to go away completely because I have duplicates of almost everyone of my songs. How will I erase all music from my phone without doing factory reset.

Answer (score 3):

Under Settings, iTunes & App Store there's an Option for "show all" (music, videos). If you disable it, it will only show you the songs that are actually on your phone, not those that are downloadable because you bought them.