# How do I remove songs from my iPhone 5s running IOS 8.3?

Tags: iphone, itunes

There is a U2 album on my iPhone which I didn't download & isn't on my Mac & I am unable to remove it.

I deleted all Music app storage from the phone, then re-synched with 1 playlist from iTunes on the Mac, but the album still appears on the phone under genres, artists & albums but not playlists.

Comment: This answer may help: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/137159/38539.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you need to do is go into settings on the iPhone, then iTunes & App Store, and disable Automatic Downloads of Music.

Apple applied the U2 album to everyones account so if u have this option turned on, then it auto downloads.

[image]